# Why does moviepy sometimes show logs stacking vertically instead of one line?

Tags: moviepy

The below is not what I want, I want it to show a single line:

```
chunk:   0%|                                                                         | 0/895 [00:00<?, ?it/s, now=None]

chunk:   0%|▏                                                                | 2/895 [00:00<03:04,  4.85it/s, now=None]

chunk:   3%|██                                                              | 28/895 [00:00<00:12, 68.76it/s, now=None]

chunk:  10%|██████▍                                                        | 91/895 [00:00<00:06, 115.41it/s, now=None]
```